# How to play the mp3 file in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am using jacvascript to play the mp3 file.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="playmusic();" value="click me">
<script type="text/javascript">
     function playmusic(){
          var audio = new Audio('flipit.mp3');
          audio.play();
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its works fine. But, in my phonegap application the mp3 file does not work.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Your code looks fine. Where's your mp3 located relative to your javascript and www? You don't need the media plugin what you're doing is enough. Also, initialize the audio once and not every time you call the play function.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this hope will work for you.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                    function playmusic()
                    {
                        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
                        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'filename.mp3');
                        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
                    }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" onclick="playmusic();" value="click me">

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media instead of audio.

```
var myaudio = new Media('flipit.mp3');
```

Try that.

EG:

```
function playStream() {
    var myaudio = new Media('flipit.mp3');
    myaudio.play();
}
```

**update based on your comment**

You need to add the media plugin to your project -

```
 phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
```

Run that above command within the project's directory and you should be set.

Comment: Am already using Media instead of Audio but i have the following error, Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/game.html:42